# awk multiple pattern match and print in single line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the following file:

```
$ cat disk.out
disk0
fcs0
text
text
text
disk1
fcs1
text
text
text
text
...
```

What I am trying to achieve is match "disk" + "fcs" and then print the pair in one line, like this:

```
disk0,fcs0
disk1,fcs1
...
```

So I am matching "disk" and "fcs" with `awk` and changing the output record separator to ",".`

```
$ awk '/disk|fcs/' ORS="," disk.out
disk0,fcs0,disk1,fcs1,
```

The problem is, it will print all the matches on one line and with a trailing `,`.
How can I print only per match in one line? Like this:

```
disk0,fcs0
disk1,fcs1
...
```

Answer (score 18):

You have to save the "disk" line (without printing it) until you find the next "fcs" line:

```
awk '/disk/{ DISK=$0; next } /fcs/{ print DISK "," $0 }'
```

The problem with your approach is that it prints *either* line matching "disk" or "fcs", without *combining* those lines.

Edit: the [script of sp asic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303918/184914) is more robust, in that it ignores

```
disk3
text
fcs3
```

My script would happily print "disk3,fcs3" in this case.

Answer (score 11):

```
$ awk '/fcs/ && a ~ /disk/ {print a","$0} {a=$0}' disk.out
disk0,fcs0
disk1,fcs1
```

`string ~ /regexp/` will check if the regexp (which is `disk` here) matches the given string, which is variable `a` in this case. The `&&` operator is used here to combine two conditions, only if the first condition `/fcs/` and the second condition `a ~ /disk/` are both true, the print will execute.

Answer (score 8):

If it's always in that format (one fcs for one disk, fcs always after disk), you could do without `awk`:

```
grep -F -e disk -e fcs file | paste -d , - -
```

Or:

```
awk '(/disk/ && ORS=",") || (/fcs/ && ORS=RS)' file
```

Though with `awk`, you may prefer a more legible approach as given by Martin or sp asic.